# What is the meaning of Political Oratory in Aristotle's Rhetoric?

Tags: rhetoric

I have understood 'Forensic Oratory' to mean courtroom persuasion. But what is the meaning of **Political Oratory** in Aristotle's Rhetoric? Is it just like presidential campaign speeches? Does it have a broader meaning?

Comment: This calls for an authority on Aristotle. May I suggest you consult 'The Complete Idiots Guide to Philosophy'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Aristotelian philosophy, not English. You cannot answer it without reading Aristotle or a study of Aristotle's writings.

Comment: Do you want to know the meaning of "political oratory" in general? If so, please clarify by editing your question. If you want to know the meaning in the context of a particular passage, that was written in English about Aristotle's rhetoric (or "Rhetoric"?), please specify that and quote it plus a link to the source in your question. Otherwise this is off-topic, as it is a question about philosophy, not English language. Don't hesitate to try visiting us again though, for English language and usage questions!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Political Oratory is not only speeches (though those are also Political Oratory), but advising and deliberating.

> "The Political Orator aims at establishing the expediency or the harmfulness of a proposed course of action; if he urges its acceptance, he does so on the ground that it will do good; if he urges its rejection, he does so on the ground that it will do harm"

A noticeable difference between Political Oratory and Forensic Oratory is that Political Oratory debates/speaks about the future and Forensic is "attacking or defending someone"

I'm not sure if you've seen this already, but [this Book describes it](http://rhetoric.eserver.org/aristotle/rhet1-3.html) a little.

see chapters 3 and 4.